# MVVM coordinators and popping a UIViewController

Tags: ios, mvvm, uinavigationcontroller

I've recently started using coordinators (Example: [MVVM with Coordinators and RxSwift](https://news.realm.io/news/mobilization-lukasz-mroz-mvvm-coordinators-rxswift/)) to improve my current MVVM architecture. It's a nice solution to remove navigation related code from the UIViewController.

But I'm having trouble with 1 specific scenario. The issue arrises when a UIViewController is popped by the default back button or edge-swipe gesture.

Quick example using a list-detail interface:

A list UIViewController is shown by a ListCoordinator inside a UINavigationController. When an item is tapped, the ListCoordinator creates a DetailCoordinator, registers it as a child coordinator and starts it. The DetailCoordinator pushes the detail UIViewController onto the UINavigationController, just like every MVVM-C blog post illustrates.

What every MVVM-C blog post fails to illustrate is what happens when the detail UIViewController is popped by the default back button or edge-swipe gesture.

The DetailCoordinator should be responsible for popping the detail UIViewController, but a) it doesn't know the back button was tapped and b) the pop happens automatically. Also, the ListCoordinator wasn't able to remove the DetailCoordinator from its child coordinators.

One solution would be to use custom back buttons, which signal the tap and pass it on to the DetailCoordinator. Another one is probably using UINavigationControllerDelegate.

How have others solved this issue? I'm sure I'm not the first one.

Comment: Why don't you use a custom button?

Answer (score 3):

I use [Action](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/Action) for communication between coordinators and also between coordinator and a view controller.

**AuthCoordinator**

```
final class AuthCoordinator: Coordinator {
    func startLogin(viewModel: LoginViewModel) {
        let loginCoordinator = LoginCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController)

        loginCoordinator.start(viewModel: viewModel)
        viewModel.coordinator = loginCoordinator

        // This is where a child coordinator removed
        loginCoordinator.stopAction = CocoaAction { [unowned self] _ in
            if let index = self.childCoordinators.index(where: { type(of: $0) == LoginCoordinator.self }) {
                self.childCoordinators.remove(at: index)
            }
            return .empty()
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginCoordinator**

```
final class LoginCoordinator: Coordinator {
    var stopAction: CocoaAction?

    func start(viewModel: LoginViewModel) {
        let loginViewController = UIStoryboard.auth.instantiate(LoginViewController.self)
        loginViewController.setViewModel(viewModel: viewModel)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: true)

        loginViewController.popAction = CocoaAction { [unowned self] _ in
            self.stopAction?.execute(Void())
            return .empty()
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginViewController**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    var popAction: CocoaAction?

    override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
        super.didMove(toParentViewController: parent)
        if parent == nil { // parent is `nil` when the vc is popped
            popAction?.execute(Void())
        }
    }
}
```

So the `LoginViewController` executes the action when it's popped. It's coordinator `LoginCoordinator` is aware that the view is popped. It triggers another action from its parent coordinator `AuthCoordinator`. The parent coordinator `AuthCoordinator` removes its child `LoginCoordinator` from the `childControllers` array/set.

BTW, why do you need to keep the child coordinators in the array and then thinking about how to remove them. I tried another approach, the child coordinator retained by a view model, once the view model deallocated, the coordinator deallocates too. Worked for me.

But I'm personally don't like so many connections and thinking about a simpler approach using a single coordinator object for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have already solved your architecture problem and if you'd like to share your solution. I asked something related to your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609844/subscribe-to-uinavigationcontroller-back-button-with-rxswift-rxcocoa) and [Daniel T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506441/daniel-t) suggested to subscribe to `navigationController.rx.willShow`: you get back events whenever a ViewController is popped OR pushed onto the view controller stack, so you need to check yourself what kind of event it is (a pop or a push). I think the viewModel / viewController shouldn't know anything of the next story to present, so I think the viewModel could emit an event ("show detail of table cell #n") and a coordinator should push or pop the right scene ("detail of cell #n"). This kind of architecture is too advanced for me to write, so I end up with a lot of circular references / memory leaks.

Comment: Another way to be notified could be to subscribe to `viewController.rx.sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.vie‌​wWillDisappear(_:)))` as suggested by [NRitH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665456/nrith) but you get events for push AND pop events as before because when a push happens `viewWillDisappear` is called for the "presenting" viewController.

Comment: I did try the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` (`willShow`) solution, while it worked for 1 `UIViewController`, it wasn't a viable solution with multiple `UIViewController`. In the end we used a custom back button which notified the view model & the view model notified the coordinator, allowing the coordinator to pop the `UIViewController`.

Comment: In [this](http://rx-marin.com/post/dotswift-rxswift-view-controller/) post Marin Todorov, one of the coauthors of RayWenderlich RxSwift Book, explains how to present a ViewController with UINavigationController and how to observe when the presented ViewController ends its work. In chapter 4 of the book he explains everything in great depth (the presented VC gives an observable that emits completed event from viewWillDisappear. The same happens when it ends its work for other reasons, but in that case it emits also a next event).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, you can solve this by using this piece of code in your coordinate method. I am specifically using didShow instead of willShow (which was suggested in another answer) for the possibility of edge swipe gestures.

```
if let topViewController = navigationController?.topViewController {
    navigationController?.rx
        .didShow
        .filter { $0.viewController == topViewController }
        .first()
        .subscribe(onSuccess: { [weak self] _ in
            // remove child coordinator
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```