# Subscribe to UINavigationController back button with RxSwift / RxCocoa

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a simple test project with a `UINavigationController` as my `rootViewController`.

I push the first `ViewController` which has a + button as right bar button item, I subscribe to its taps to present a new `ViewController` (which is identical to the previous one).
The push segue works as I expect.

`UIKit` manages the back button for me and I think it is `UINavigationController` that makes the magic behind the scene.

Now, what I need to do is subscribe to the back button, but I can't find how to do this.
I have tried with

1. `navigationController.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.rx.tap`
2. `navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.rx.tap`
   but they seem to be nil, so the optional chaining prevents subscription.

Thanks for your help, Luca-

Comment: Why do you need to subscribe to the back button? The current view controller will be popped off of the navigation controller's stack, and the previous view controller will become the new current view controller. If you need that new current view controller to do something after it's back on top, then you should put that code in its `viewWillAppear(animated:)` method, which is called every time a view controller becomes the topmost one on a nav controller or is presented modally.

Comment: Thank you NRitH for your suggestions. I am exploring how ViewController navigation works with RxSwift / RxCocoa. I'd like to have a Coordinator that instantiates ViewControllers and ViewModels. I think navigation should be orchestrated by these Coordinator objects and to do that they need to know when the user taps the back button. Anyway, this is pretty confused in my mind, but viewController.rx.sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.viewWillDisappear(_:))) works as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet here is to use the operator on UINavigationController.

`navigationController.rx.willShow` will trigger whenever a view controller is about to be shown. You can do any last minute clean up when it fires.

Comment: UINavigationController doesn't seem to have a rx.willShow observable. Am I missing something? Do I have to use a #selector?

Comment: Maybe you need to upgrade to the latest version of RxCocoa? It's there (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/UINavigationController%2BRx.swift)

Comment: The new RxSwift book by raywenderlich explains how to implement rx methods for any delegate, including the UINavigationControllerDelegate. (https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/rxswift)

Comment: I bought that book on day 0, but I find it pretty hard to follow if I don't try things myself. UINavigationControllerDelegate is something obscure: I need to give it a second read...